# How to handle onclick event with DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, onclick

I have a script that initializes DataTables and reloads content every few seconds.

I would like to add `onclick` event handler, but not sure how to structure the file. The way it is now, the `openPoolModal` function is triggered on page refresh without any click occuring. That leads to failed `DataTables` initialization as a modal dialog is opened and no tables are present.

When I move the `onclick` line after the `DataTables` initialization the `getElementById` just returns null.

```
   var table;

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#main-table').on("click", "tr", openPoolModal(document.getElementById("hashrateId").innerText));

table = $('#main-table').DataTable({
            ajax: {
                url: '/refresh',
                dataSrc:''
            },
           paging: true,
           lengthChange: false,
           pageLength: 20,
           stateSave: true,
           info: true,
           searching: false,
           "columnDefs": [
                 {
                 "className": "text-center",
                 "targets": 0,
                 "data": "id",
                 },

                 {
                 "className": "text-center",
                 "targets": 1,
                 "data" : function(data){

                     var seconds = data.repDate.second < 10 ? seconds = "0" + data.repDate.second : seconds = data.repDate.second;
                     var minutes = data.repDate.minute < 10 ? minutes = "0" + data.repDate.minute : minutes = data.repDate.minute;
                     var months = data.repDate.monthValue < 10 ? months = "0" + data.repDate.monthValue : months = data.repDate.monthValue;
                     var days = data.repDate.dayOfMonth < 10 ? days = "0" + data.repDate.dayOfMonth : days = data.repDate.dayOfMonth;

                     return data.repDate.year + "-" + months + "-" + days + "   " + data.repDate.hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
                    },
                 },

                 {
                 "className": "text-center",
                 "targets": 2,
                 "data": function(data){
                    return data.hashrate/1000.0;
                    },
                 }
           ],
           "aoColumns": [
             { "orderSequence": [ "asc", "desc" ] },
             { "orderSequence": [ "asc", "desc" ] },
             { "orderSequence": [ "desc", "asc" ] }
           ],
           "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]]
});
});

setInterval(function(){
table.ajax.reload(null, false);
}, 8000);
```

I have also tried such on click implementation, but with same result:

```
$('#main-table').on('click', 'tr', function () {

    var id = document.getElementById("hashrateId").innerText;
    console.log(id);

    openPoolModal(document.getElementById("hashrateId").innerText);
} );
```

Html table:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="main-table">

                        <thead class="thead-inverse">
                        <tr >
                            <th class="col-md-2 text-center">Network Id</th>
                            <th class="col-md-2 text-center">Rep date</th>
                            <th class="col-md-2 text-center">Hashrate [KH/s]</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                        <tr id="tableRow" style="cursor: pointer;" th:each="networkHashrate : ${networkHashrates}" th:onclick="'javascript:openPoolModal(\''+ ${networkHashrate.id} + '\');'">
                            <td class="text-center" id="hashrateId" th:text="${networkHashrate.id}"> Sample id</td>
                            <td class="text-center" id="repDate" th:text="${@findAndDisplayDataService.formatDate(networkHashrate.repDate)}">Sample rep-date</td>
                            <td class="text-center" id="hashrate" th:text="${@findAndDisplayDataService.formatHashrate(networkHashrate.hashrate)}">Sample hashrate</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null`. Same, the returned `getElement` is `Null`..

Comment: `table.on('click', 'tr', function () {

    var id = $(this).find("td#hashrateId").text();
    console.log(id);

    openPoolModal(document.getElementById("hashrateId").innerText);
} );`

Comment: Doesn't work. I guess the problem is that my `ajax.reload` function just clears all the `html` tags, ids etc. So that's why `getElementBy` & `find` doesn't work. Any more clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will now try to answer through [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on('click', '#main-table tbody tr', function () { 
  var hashrateId = $(this).find("td").eq(0).text(); 
  console.log(hashrateId); 
  //openPoolModal(hashrateId); 
});
```

Put this code separately from the other code you have.